# Show that $\hat{f}$ can be written in the form $ \hat{f}(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{\alpha}_iK(\cdot, x_i) $

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization

In binary classification, one observes a collection of pairs $\{(x_i, y_i)\}$ where each feature vector $x_i\in R^d$ is associated with a label $y_i\in \{-1,+1\}$. In reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces, we want to minimize a criterion of the form
$$
\hat{f}=\arg \min_{f\in H}\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if(x_i)\}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_n\|f\|_H^2\right\}
$$
where $H$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, $\lambda_n>0$ is a user-defined regularization parameter. The classification rule is given by $x\mapsto sign(\hat{f}(x))$.

Show that $\hat{f}$ can be written in the form
$$
\hat{f}(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{\alpha}_iK(\cdot, x_i)
$$
for some vector $\hat{\alpha}\in R^n$.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are asking about is a special case of the more general [Representer Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representer_theorem).

Your starting point for the proof is right : let $f=f_+ + f_-$ with $f_+\in\mathrm{span}(\{K(\cdot, x_i)\}_{i=1}^n)$ and $f_+\perp f_-$. The idea is to show that the functional
$$J:f\mapsto \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if(x_i)\}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_n\|f\|_H^2 $$
Can only attain its minimum when $f_-=0$.

To see this, first note that $\|f\|_H^2  = \|f_+ + f_-\|_H^2 = \|f_+\|_H^2 + \|f_-\|_H^2 + 2\langle f_+,f_-\rangle =\|f_+\|_H^2 + \|f_-\|_H^2  $ by orthogonality assumption.
From this observation it follows that $ \|f\|_H^2 \ge \|f_+\|_H^2$.

Secondly, by the reproducing property, you have that
$$f(x_i) = \langle f,K(\cdot,x_i)\rangle = \langle f_+,K(\cdot,x_i)\rangle + \langle f_-,K(\cdot,x_i)\rangle = \langle f_+,K(\cdot,x_i)\rangle $$
Because $f_-$ is orthogonal to $\mathrm{span}(\{K(\cdot, x_i)\}_{i=1}^n)$.

From this observation, it follows that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if(x_i)\} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if_+(x_i)\} $$

Hence, for all $f$
$$\begin{align}J(f_+)-J(f)&=\frac 1 2 \lambda_n\|f_+\|_H^2 - \frac 1 2 \lambda_n\|f\|_H^2\\
&= \frac 1 2 \lambda_n(\|f_+\|_H^2 -\|f\|_H^2)\\
&\le 0 \text{ (assuming $\lambda_n\ge 0$)}\end{align} $$
From which we can conclude that the minimizer(s) of $J$ have to be elements of $\mathrm{span}(\{K(\cdot, x_i)\}_{i=1}^n)$.

Comment: Oops, you're right, my triangle inequality was in the wrong direction. Sorry about that ! Regarding your second question, I just proved that a solution $\hat f$ has to lie in the span of the $K(\cdot,x_i)$, i.e. there exist coefficients $\alpha_i$ such that
$$ \hat{f}(\cdot)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha}_iK(\cdot, x_i)$$
So if you let $\hat\alpha_i := \sqrt n \alpha_i$ for all $i$, it follows that
$$\hat{f}(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{\alpha}_iK(\cdot, x_i)$$

Comment: Oops, again, thanks for pointing this out ! Just fixed it. Hopefully there are no mistakes left now !

Comment: Thanks! Can you please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411192/penalized-form-of-the-nonparametric-least-squares-estimate?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you replace the problem $$\hat{f}=\arg \min_{f\in H}\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if(x_i)\}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_n\|f\|_H^2\right\}$$ to an approximated problem with  finite dimension, given by  $$\hat{f}=\arg \min_{f=\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha}_iK(\cdot, x_i)}\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0, 1-y_if(x_i)\}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_n\|f\|_H^2\right\}.$$

Please see comments around equation (2.2) in [this arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00453.pdf) file. See also Lemma 2.3 of the same file.

You can search to "(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max{0, 1-y_if(x_i)) " on SearchOnMath to find some threads and related arxiv files.